# three js clickable objects

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have two 3d objects "meshes" that I created in three.js. 
I want to add click event to these objects so that when I click on one of them, it is scaled up and when I click on the other one, it rotates.

I tried this method to add a click event to an object and it's not working.

```
<script src='threex.domevent.js'> </script>
<script>

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 100;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);

        cube.addEventListener( 'click',function(){cubeScale()} , false );

        function cubeScale()
            {
            cube.scale.x *= 20;
            }


        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            cube.rotation.y += 0.1;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();

    </script>
```

Comment: see http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html

Comment: also see http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes_tween.html

Answer (score 21):

you can use this event manager [three.interaction](https://github.com/jasonChen1982/three.interaction.js)

and see this [demo](https://jasonchen1982.github.io/three.interaction.js/examples/interaction/)

```js
import { Scene, PerspectiveCamera, WebGLRenderer, Mesh, BoxGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial } from 'three';
import { Interaction } from 'three.interaction';

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvasElement });
const scene = new Scene();
const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(60, width / height, 0.1, 100);

// new a interaction, then you can add interaction-event with your free style
const interaction = new Interaction(renderer, scene, camera);

const cube = new Mesh(
  new BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
  new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }),
);
scene.add(cube);
cube.cursor = 'pointer';
cube.on('click', function(ev) {});
cube.on('touchstart', function(ev) {});
cube.on('touchcancel', function(ev) {});
cube.on('touchmove', function(ev) {});
cube.on('touchend', function(ev) {});
cube.on('mousedown', function(ev) {});
cube.on('mouseout', function(ev) {});
cube.on('mouseover', function(ev) {});
cube.on('mousemove', function(ev) {});
cube.on('mouseup', function(ev) {});
// and so on ...

/**
 * you can also listen on parent-node or any display-tree node,
 * source event will bubble up along with display-tree.
 * you can stop the bubble-up by invoke ev.stopPropagation function.
 */
scene.on('touchstart', ev => {
  console.log(ev);
})
scene.on('touchmove', ev => {
  console.log(ev);
})
```

Comment: Nice demo, and nice answer as well !

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely you need to implement **raycaster** to select/click/pick certain object in three.js. I've already implemented it in one of my project using three.js and raycaster against collada model. For your reference, these links can help you:

1. http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/object-picking/
2. http://jensarps.de/2012/08/10/mouse-picking-collada-models-with-three-js/

Comment: the first link besides this link: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366109/three-js-three-projector-has-been-moved-to" helped me so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pickingRay` to perform clicking with orthographic camera  like that follows in this code:

```js
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
      (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
      -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);

var rayCaster = projector.pickingRay(vector, camera);

var intersectedObjects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
```

But if you want perform clicking on perspective camera you have to perform an clicking using the `unprojectVector` like that follows below:

```js
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 
     (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, 
     - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 
                0.5 );

var rayCaster = projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

var intersectedObjects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(objects);
```