# Three.js THREE.Projector has been moved to

Tags: javascript, three.js

I understand there is no `THREE.projector` in version 71 (see the [deprecated list](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/deprecated/DeprecatedList)), but I don't understand how to replace it, particularly in this code that detects which object has been clicked on:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
  (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
  -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
  0.5
);
projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(
  camera.position,
  vector.sub(camera.position).normalize()
);
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
if (intersects.length > 0) {
  clicked = intersects[0];
  console.log("my clicked object:", clicked);
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is now an easier pattern that works with both orthographic and perspective camera types:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); // create once
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); // create once

...

mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, recursiveFlag );
```

three.js r.84

Comment: Can you explain objects and recursiveFlag here with an actual example?

Comment: Also what is renderer and domElement in this context?

Answer (score 13):

The [THREE.JS raycaster documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster) actually gives all the relevant information that is laid out in these answers as well as all the missing points that may be difficult to get your head around.

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); 
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); 

function onMouseMove( event ) { 
  // calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates 
  // (-1 to +1) for both components 
  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1; 
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1; 
} 

function render() { 
  // update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera ); 
  // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray var intersects =     
  raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children ); 

  for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) { 
    intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 ); 
  }

  renderer.render( scene, camera ); 
} 
window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );        
window.requestAnimationFrame(render);`
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5587

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var dir = new THREE.Vector3();

...

if ( camera instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

    vector.set( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, - 1 ); // z = - 1 important!

    vector.unproject( camera );

    dir.set( 0, 0, - 1 ).transformDirection( camera.matrixWorld );

    raycaster.set( vector, dir );

} else if ( camera instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

    vector.set( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 ); // z = 0.5 important!

    vector.unproject( camera );

    raycaster.set( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

}

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, recursiveFlag );
```

---

Objects = array of objects of type Object3D to check for intersection with the ray. Can be everything in your scene, but might be inefficient if you have a lot of stuff there.

recursiveFlag =  If true, it also checks all descendants. Otherwise it only checks intersection with the object. Default is true.

[docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=raycaster#api/en/core/Raycaster)

Comment: can you give us a complete example? what is objects? what is recursiveFlag? and what is ... ? thx

Comment: I agree no idea what objects and recursiveFlag is?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the latest recommended version as stated above.

To get your specific code working, replace:

```
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
```

with

```
vector.unproject(camera);
```

Comment: Are you repeating an earlier answer, you could upvote it ?

Answer (score 2):

I noted that all this that was said before is fine in a full window I think, but if you have other things besides a canvas on the page you need to get the click events target's offset and remove it.

e = event and mVec is a THREE.Vector2

```
    let et = e.target, de = renderer.domElement;
    let trueX = (e.pageX - et.offsetLeft);
    let trueY = (e.pageY - et.offsetTop);
    mVec.x = (((trueX / de.width) * 2) - 1);
    mVec.y = (((trueY / de.height) * -2) + 1);
    wup.raycaster.setFromCamera( mVec, camera );
    [Then check for intersections, etc.]
```

Looks like you need to watch for dragging (mouse movements) too or releasing from a drag will trigger an unwanted click when using window.addEventListener( 'click', function(e) {<code>});

[You'll notice I put the negative sign where it's more logical as well.]

Comment: Oooooh god thank you ! Thank you ! I was sure my raycasting wasn't okey because of my offset ! My brain couldn't find a way to get the good values !
For the others : Yeah, our canvas may not be a fullscreen one ! >.< Brrrrrr

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share my experiences with more details doing this since I feel the answers above do not really explain the details to get this going.

In my case I was using STL_Viewer, you can locate it here (https://www.viewstl.com/plugin/), it helps create a threeJS scene and supplies you with the **camera** and **scene** that you will need for this to work.

```
function mouse_click_normalize(clientX,clientY,offset_left,offset_top){
                var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); // create once
                var c = document.getElementById("stl_contEye").childNodes[0];//get canvas element created in here
                mouse.x = ( (event.clientX-offset_left) / (c.clientWidth)  * 2) - 1;
                mouse.y = - ( (event.clientY-offset_top) / (c.clientHeight) ) * 2 + 1;
                console.log(`clientX=${clientX},clientY=${clientY},mouse.x=${mouse.x},mouse.y=${mouse.y}\nwidth=${c.clientWidth},height=${c.clientHeight},offset_left=${offset_left},offset_top=${offset_top}`);
                return mouse;
           }
```

Above is my function that will automatically normalize the x,y coordinates in the space that was clicked (between -1 and 1), as this is what the raycaster requires for it's setFromCamera function.

Because you may be clicking in a section of the screen with offsets I programmed it this way so it will handle no matter how it's positioned in the DOM.  Just replace "stl_contEye" with the name of your div that will contain the rendered ThreeJS or STLViewer in my case.

```
function model_clicked(model_id, e, distance, click_type){
                console.log(e);
                
                var pos = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once and reuse
                // var vec = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once and reuse
                
                var camera = stl_viewer1.camera;
                var scene = stl_viewer1.scene;
                // vec.unproject( camera );
                // vec.sub( camera.position ).normalize();
                // //var distance2 = (distance - camera.position.z) / vec.z;
                // pos.copy( camera.position ).add( vec.multiplyScalar( distance ) );
                var mouse_coords_normalized = mouse_click_normalize(e.clientX,e.clientY,e.srcElement.offsetLeft,e.srcElement.offsetTop);
                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); // create once
                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse_coords_normalized, camera );
                //console.log(raycaster);
                //console.log(scene);

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
                if(intersects.length > 0){
                    console.log(intersects);
                    console.log(intersects[0].point);
                    pos = intersects[0].point
                }
}
```

By doing it this way, you will get the exact point in 3D space from where you clicked.  The function model_clicked simply returns an event that holds the clientX or clientY, you just have to get this yourself somehow if you are not using STLViewers event for detecting a click.  There are many examples above for this from the other answers.

I hope this helps someone trying to figure this out with or without stl_viewer

Answer (score -1):

```
camera.shooting = Date.now()

        document.getElementById("div5").addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
        document.getElementById("div5").addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
    
        document.getElementById("div5").addEventListener( 'mousemove', renderq);
    function mousedown(event) {
    camera.calculator = 1;
    
    
    }
    function mouseup(event) {
     
    camera.calculator = 0;
       

}
    
    function renderq(event){
        
            
     if( ai2bcz.length > 0 &&  ai_key3.length > 0  ){
    
     if( camera.calculator > 0   ){
    
    
        
    camera.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        
    
    var fleece = document.getElementById("div5").scrollHeight;
    var fleeceb =  document.getElementById("div5").scrollWidth;
    var fees = (event.clientX / fleeceb)  - 1;
        var feesa = - (event.clientY  / fleece)  + 1;
     camera.mouse.x = fees ;  camera.mouse.y  = feesa;  
    
    var sphereMaterialc = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0099FF});
    var sphereGeoc = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 5, 5);
    var spherec = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeoc, sphereMaterialc);
        spherec.position.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
    
        
       
        spherec.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
       
       spherec.raycaster.setFromCamera( camera.mouse, camera);
            
            
        spherec.owner = 'player';
    
        spherec.health = 100;
        
        bulletsc.push(spherec);
        scene.add(spherec);
    camera.lastshot = Date.now();
    camera.shooting = Date.now();
    }
    }
    
    }
    function render() { const controlscamera = new FirstPersonControls(camera);
        
    controlscamera.update(100);
    
            
     if( ai2bcz.length > 0 &&  ai_key3.length > 0  ){
    
     if( camera.calculator > 0 && camera.shooting + 25 < Date.now()  ){
     renderq(event)
    camera.shooting = Date.now();
    }} 
    
    
    if(bulletsc.length > 1){
    
        for (var i = 0; i < bulletsc.length - 1; i++) {
    
            
            
    var bu = bulletsc[i], pu = bu.position, du = bu.raycaster.ray.direction;
    
    
    if(bu.owner == "player"){
    
    
    
                
                
    var enemybulletspeeda = window.document.getElementById("bulletsplayerspeed").value;
                bu.translateX(enemybulletspeeda * du.x);
                bu.translateY(enemybulletspeeda * du.y);
                bu.translateZ(enemybulletspeeda * du.z);
    
    }
    
    
        
    
    }}
    
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera ); }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).