# Raycaster Not Detecting Certain Objects - Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been trying to add a raycaster to my game for some time now. After testing a lot of situations, I have found that the raycaster IS functioning.

There is a scene that contains various enemy objects, and a floor. Same scene. A raycaster is supposed to be sending a ray out from the cursor to things on this scene. However, only the floor is detected as a collision, while all of the other objects cannot be detected.

This is currently being hosted here: http://aceverything.com/cskelly/project2/

Here are some relevant fragments:

```
function render() {
            //console.log(object.position);
            // LATER: IMPLEMENT NICER GUN ANIMATION
            global_m60.position.x += ( mouseX - global_m60.position.x ) * .45;
            if(-mouseY < 1){
            global_m60.position.y += ( - mouseY - global_m60.position.y ) * .45;
            }
            else{
            global_m60.position.y = 1;
            }

            for(i = 0; i < enemy_tanks.length ; ++i){
             enemy_tanks[i].position.z += .01;
            }

            projector.unprojectVector( mouse, camera );   
            mouse.sub( camera.position );                
            mouse.normalize();
            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, mouse );
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
            for( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; ++i ){
                intersects[i].object.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("models/red_checkerboard.jpg");
                intersects[i].object.material.needsUpdate = true;
                console.log("RAY STUFF HAPPENING");
            }


            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.clear();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            renderer.clearDepth();
            renderer.render( sandbag_scene, camera );
            renderer.clearDepth();
            renderer.render( scene2, camera );
            framecount += 1;

        }
```

Me loading in the objects that are NOT being detected:

```
    // ENEMIES
            mtlLoader.setPath('models/');

            for(i = 0; i < max_tanks; ++i){
            mtlLoader.load( 'ultimate-tank.mtl', function( materials2 ) {

                //materials2.needsUpdate = true;
                materials2.preload();

                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials2 );
                //objLoader.setPath( 'obj/male02/' );
                objLoader.load( 'models/ultimate-tank.obj', function ( object2 ) {

                    object2.position.x = (Math.random()*30)-15;
                    object2.position.y = -1;
                    object2.position.z = 220;
                    //object2.position.y = -95;
                    global_enemy_1 = object2;
                    global_enemy_1.rotateY(1.507);
                    //global_enemy_1.renderOrder = 1;
                    enemy_tanks.push(global_enemy_1);
                    scene.add( global_enemy_1 ); // THIS HAS TO BE DONE LIKE THIS.
                    //global_enemy_1.material.color.set( 0xff0000 ); THIS DOESNT WORK...



                }, onProgress, onError );

            }); 
            }
```

The original intention was to change the material of objects the raycaster comes into contact with to visually show me that there was a collision. The material part is irrelevant. The part that matters is that:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

clearly isn't giving me the objects. What gives?

Comment: Try to use `raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children , true)`.

Comment: Yep! That fixed it! Why is that the case? :)

Comment: Just checked the documentation and noticed the "recursive" part. Guess it didn't click with me that that is what it meant. Thank you for pointing it out to me - if you make this an answer I'll accept it. Sorry for the silly question!

Comment: Tip: How many raycasters are you instantiating? Instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366109/three-js-three-projector-has-been-moved-to/29373404#29373404.