# Three.js: not accurate to detect faceIndex when clicking the 2*2*2 geometry cube

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I have created a 2*2*2 geometry cube via Three.js. Now I want to detect the click event when clicking the faces (24 faces in total).

Please check my current implementation at https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/pdwg3myr/17/. When clicking on the faces, I want to `console.log` the current face index. But the index is not always accurate. For example, clicking on the top-left gray cell should show 0, but actually clicking the bottom part of it shows 2.

Please help me to check the mouse click event handler:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

   var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 
      ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, 
      - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
   vector.unproject( camera );
   raycaster.setFromCamera( vector, camera );
   raycaster.set( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

   var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( cube );
   if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
      var index = Math.floor( intersects[0].faceIndex / 2 );
      console.log(index);
   }
}
```

Could anybody please help?

Comment: Too late, but, I did [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pdwg3myr/21/) for you to help with debugging. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366109/three-js-three-projector-has-been-moved-to/29373404#29373404.

Comment: @WestLangley great thanks

Answer (score 7):

Em, after googling a lot, I found [this page](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Click.html) and applied the approach. It's working properly https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/pdwg3myr/19/:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(cube);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    var index = Math.floor(intersects[0].faceIndex / 2);
    console.log(index);
  }
}
```

### Update

To adjust to the left/top shift and scrolling, update it to https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/pdwg3myr/24/:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  const holder = renderer.domElement;
  const rect = holder.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse.x = ((event.pageX - rect.left - window.scrollX) / holder.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -((event.pageY - rect.top - window.scrollY) / holder.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
  ...
}
```

Comment: hours of googling and the left/top shifting was what I was missing, thanks!